# Why does Transpose Function gives error at times in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I wrote this code to transpose the Data frame, the odd part of this is this code works quite a lot of times and at times it doesn't work, which is baffling.

```
Book5<- read_excel("C:/X/X/X/X/1.1 Croston_Aplha-0.1.xlsx")
X1 <- transpose(Book5,keep.names="rn")
```

The error I get for this is:

> ```
> Error in transpose(Book5, keep.names = "rn") : 
>   unused argument (keep.names = "rn")
> ```

Dput for the data frame is :

```
structure(list(`Row Labels` = c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", 
"2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-08-01", 
"2019-09-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", 
"2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", 
"2020-07-01", "2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", "2020-10-01", "2020-11-01", 
"2020-12-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-04-01", 
"2021-05-01", "2021-06-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-08-01", "2021-09-01", 
"2021-10-01", "2021-11-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", 
"2022-03-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-06-01", "2022-07-01", 
"2022-08-01", "2022-09-01", "2022-10-01"), `XYZ|146` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 18, 16, 16, 17, 12, 22, 6, 
7, 6, 0, 15, 0, 17, 17, 5, 19, 16, 7, 25, 19, 34, 26, 41, 50, 
29, 42, 20, 14, 16, 27, 10, 28, 21), `XYZ|666` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 45, 
9, 21, 33, 3, 8, 11, 16, 3, 17, 14, 59, 26, 35, 26, 15, 7, 4, 
4, 2, 7, 6, 2), `XYZ|574` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 74, 179, 
464, 880, 324, 184, 90, 170, 140, 96, 78, 83, 83, 121, 245, 740, 
332, 123, 117, 138, 20, 42, 70, 70, 42, 103, 490, 641, 488, 245, 
142, 95, 63, 343, 57, 113, 100, 105), `XYZ|851` = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 206, 1814, 2324, 772, 1116, 1636, 1906, 957, 
829, 911, 786, 938, 1313, 2384, 1554, 1777, 1635, 1534, 1015, 
827, 982, 685, 767, 511, 239, 1850, 1301, 426, 261, 201, 33, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-46L))
```

Can someone tell me why is this acting like this? The expected output is given below:

[image]

Comment: Can you copy the data from sheet (of expected output) and paste it in the question as text instead of an image?

Comment: Also, is `Book5` well defined?

Comment: From your code I guess that you want the `transpose` function from `data.table`. Note however that there is also a `transpose` function in `purrr` (which has no `keep.names` argument). Hence when you use both packages the issue might be that `data.table::transpose` is masked by `purrr::transpose`. One possible fix might be to use `data.table::transpose(Book5,keep.names="rn")`.

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much for clarification. If you can post this as answer. I could mark it as answer.